# Filter to remove all rows before a particular value in a specific column, while this particular value occurs several time

Tags: r, filter

I would like to filter to remove all rows before a particular value in a specific column. For example, in the data frame below, I would like to remove all rows before "1" that appears in column x, for as much as "1" occurs. Please note that the value of "1" repeats many times and I want to remove the "NA" rows before the "1" in column x, regarding column a.
Thanks

```
a   b   x
1   1   NA
1   2   NA
1   3   1
1   4   0
1   5   0
1   6   NA
1   7   NA
2   1   NA
2   2   NA
2   3   1
2   4   NA
2   5   0
2   6   0
2   7   NA
3   1   NA
3   2   NA
3   3   NA
3   4   NA
3   5   1
3   6   0
3   7   NA
```

the desired output would be like this:

```
a   b   x
1   3   1
1   4   0
1   5   0
1   6   NA
1   7   NA
2   3   1
2   4   NA
2   5   0
2   6   0
2   7   NA
3   5   1
3   6   0
3   7   NA
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows imediatelly before or all rows before "bob"

Comment: Removing all rows before any bob will remove all rows before the last bob

Comment: It would help to show the desired output - especially having edited the question. We are still not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.table(text = "a   b   x
1   1   NA
1   2   NA
1   3   1
1   4   0
1   5   0
1   6   NA
1   7   NA
2   1   NA
2   2   NA
2   3   1
2   4   NA
2   5   0
2   6   0
2   7   NA
3   1   NA
3   2   NA
3   3   NA
3   4   NA
3   5   1
3   6   0
3   7   NA", header = TRUE)

dat %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(cummax(!is.na(x)) == 1)
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#> # Groups:   a [3]
#>        a     b     x
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     3     1
#>  2     1     4     0
#>  3     1     5     0
#>  4     1     6    NA
#>  5     1     7    NA
#>  6     2     3     1
#>  7     2     4    NA
#>  8     2     5     0
#>  9     2     6     0
#> 10     2     7    NA
#> 11     3     5     1
#> 12     3     6     0
#> 13     3     7    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That is what we were thinking about, when we asked for clarifications from the OP. That said, I think your first example would be a little clearer if we used `cumsum` , as in `dat[cumsum(dat$a=='bob')>0,]`. It is still not clear what the OP wants, though.

Comment: Thanks @GuedesBF; OP has updated their question with input/expected output and I believe my answer is now more inline with what they want. Thanks for the advice all the same - always appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you!!!yes.  dat %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(cummax(!is.na(x)) == 1). it solved my problem

Comment: Thank you for editing your question to include the required details; the input / expected output made it much easier to provide a solution. There are some great hints for creating 'easy-to-answer' questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example